# Is it more efficient to boil water in a pot on the electric stove than in an electric kettle?

Tags: electrical, water, kitchens, heating, stove

Water heating consumes a noticeable portion in a paycheck for the electricity. Saving on water heating did affect the cost. I also dropped the electric kettle for the electric stove. Is it more efficient to boil water in a pot on the electric stove than in an electric kettle?

Comment: Did your electric bill go up or down? That's the only way to tell if it's "worth it". Unfortunately, "is it worth it" questions are opinion based and explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: If you want the absolutes most efficient, a small immersion heater is the way to go, but all electric heat generation is 100% efficient, it's the transfer to the food where losses occur, but heating water is the easiest thing to do efficiency-speaking, so all solutions are fairly comparable; don't expect a big cost break by swapping methods. If you can find an old teapot with a concave bottom and use that with a gas stove or alcohol burner, it's likely to fare quite well in the columns of cost and time, even if overall it's energy efficiency isn't as good.

Answer (score 3):

Kettle is more efficient to heat water. Stove you have waste heat going not into the water - kettle it's all going into the water, particularly if you choose an insulated exterior type kettle, rather than a single-wall metal or glass type. But the coupling to the heating element is better in any case. If you're using an open pot on the stove rather than a closed kettle, the evaporation adds additional inefficiency to the process. A lid would solve that, but it's still less efficient.

Use either the kettle minimum to prevent burnout or the amount of water you need (whichever is larger) - don't fill the kettle to the maximum unless you need that much.

According to [this article](https://insideenergy.org/2016/02/23/boiling-water-ieq/), an induction-type electric stove is slightly more efficient (85%) than a kettle (80%). Until somone makes an induction-type well-insulated kettle, anyway. They put a normal electric stovetop at 70%, and a microwave oven at 50%. Those are *averages* and individual results will vary depending on details of the appliance and water container. They show one example of measuring specific appliances that does vary somewhat from that, but is in line with it.